# Django Form no space validator (RegexValidator)

Tags: python, regex, django, forms

I wrote this validator:

```
no_space_validator = RegexValidator(
    r'^[^\s]+$',
    _('No spaces allowed'),
    code='invalid_username')
```

and I have it set in the Form field:

```
username = CharField(
    label='Username',
    validators=[no_space_validator])
```

But still it allows me to submit usernames with spaces. I can't see how me regex is wrong here or how can I express no spaces in any other way.

Comment: _https://regex101.com/r/dP1xX0/1_ .. Are you sure regex is the problem?

Comment: What happens when you write the validator like this: `RegexValidator(regex=r'^[^\s]+$', message=_('No space allowed'), code='invalid_username')`? [For some people, this seems to work](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17051#comment:6).

Comment: @xyres, the same happens. No validation whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this (note the capital S):

```
no_space_validator = RegexValidator(
    r'^[^\S]+$',
    _('No spaces allowed'),
    code='invalid_username')
```

Read the docs for more info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#regexvalidator

Answer (score 1):

Here is more simple approach:

```
  no_space_validator = RegexValidator(
      r' ',
      _('No spaces allowed'),
      inverse_match=True,
      code='invalid_tag',
  )
```

Comment: What is with the underscore??

Comment: Oh, that is usually used in Django for translations, imported like `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`